# Import Multiple Excel files to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, import

I have about 40+ excel files that I would like to import to SQL Server 2012. The import wizard is a great tool but it only allows me to import one file at a time.

I want to avoid using SSIS because the import should be relatively easy - basically it is just a direct copy-paste with the first row in the Excel files being the column names, and the Excel Files name = Table Name.

Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Edited: Since the columns will change quite frequently, I would like to avoid creating the tables manually. The wizard is great because it will create the table for me automatically.

Comment: You can do it using OpenRowSet

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more? Is that a tool, function, or a software?

Comment: By OpenRowSet , you will create the new table during import

Comment: What you need is an SSIS packages to loop through all the execl files and import data into sql server, here is a great example of how to do it with a sample project [`How to loop through files in a specified folder, load one by one and move to archive folder using SSIS`](http://help.pragmaticworks.com/dtsxchange/scr/FAQ%20-%20How%20to%20loop%20through%20files%20in%20a%20specified%20folder,%20load%20one%20by%20one%20and%20move%20to%20archive%20folder%20using%20SSIS.htm)

Comment: I answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122538/import-multiple-excel-files-into-sql-server-2008-r2-using-ssis-packages/51719984#51719984

Answer (score 1):

A solution I used is to combine multiple Excel files into one with multiple sheets. This can be done by running a VBA script (for example [How to merge Excel files with VBA - thanks to Svetlana Cheusheva](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/11/08/merge-multiple-excel-files-into-one/)) then use the SSMS import wizard to load multiple sheets into multiple tables. In my case, I have 160 files, but they are not very big — 100 to 10000 rows — and it worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using OpenRowSet. The OPENROWSET function can be referenced in the FROM clause of a query as though it is a table name.

Read excel using the following SELECT statement together with the OPENROWSET function

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
                'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\Source\Addresses.xls;IMEX=1',
                'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

To import this to a SQL Server table without using DTS, since you are able to read the data using the SELECT statement, you can simply add the INTO clause to insert the records into a new SQL Server table.

```
SELECT * 
INTO [dbo].[Addresses_NewTable]
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
                'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\Source\Addresses.xls;IMEX=1',
                'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

Reference article:- http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/read-import-excel-file-p03.aspx

Comment: I'm getting an error message: Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: To create a linked server that accesses an Excel spreadsheet, you have to execute sp_addlinkedserver. follow http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175866(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Msg 15028, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_addlinkedserver, Line 82
The server 'EXCEL' already exists.
Msg 7302, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: When I executed sp_addlinkedserver, it was successful. But then I'm still getting the `Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)".`. When I tried to re-exec again, it says the link already exist

Answer (score 0):

It may be more research than you want to put into your problem, but you might also look into using BIML to script out the tedious and numerous similar packages.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/100550/
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3094/introduction-to-business-intelligence-markup-language-biml-for-ssis/

Answer (score 0):

Use Kutools for Excel to merge the worksheets across workbooks into one worksheet in a new workbook and then load that.

https://www.extendoffice.com/product/kutools-for-excel/merge-excel-wordbooks.html#a4

That's what I'm doing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.